# Discord bot is not keeping the string value overnight

Tags: javascript, python, discord

Below is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

swingsMessage = "Update me"


@client.command()
async def swings(ctx):
    await ctx.send(swingsMessage)


@client.command()
async def update(ctx,*,message):
    if str(ctx.message.author) == "buysellshort#9420":
        global swingsMessage
        swingsMessage = message
```

the user types !update and a message in 1 line, and the bot reads it and when users type !swings it displays that message. now this works, and it runs fine, but the next day it goes back to "Update me" it's hosted on Heroku and it's a dyno bot.

Any advice? is the code wrong, or do you guys believe that the linux machine it's being hosted on just turns off, and thats why its getting reset?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it sleeps after 30 min timeout of not receiving any traffic.

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic
> in a 30-minute period, it will sleep. In addition to the web dyno
> sleeping, the worker dyno (if present) will also sleep.
>
> Free web dynos do not consume free dyno hours while sleeping.
>
> If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active
> again after a short delay (assuming your account has free dyno hours
> available).

[Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)

Comment: so basically someone has to type !update atleast every 30 minutes for it to continue working?

Comment: @user5428151 yes, that should help

Answer (score 0):

On your Procfile, instead of `web` you can replace that with `worker`. That will get rid of the 30-minute inactivity, but watch out since it'll be working 24/7 and can eat your hours quickly.